# Does FastAPI ecosystem has analogs to Django storages?

Tags: python, fastapi

Does FastAPI ecosystem has analogs to Django storages?

Django has a nice concept of storages - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-file-storage/

It lets you easily switch between different file storages (e.g. filesystem storage vs s3). All you have to do is download or write a custom storage class and plug it in using Django settings.

What do you use when dealing with file storage in FastAPI? Do you write your custom storage library or does FastAPI ecosystem has some defacto storage library?

BTW: I use TortoiseORM as ORM, but it doesn't even have FileFields, nothing to say about storages.

Comment: FastAPI is a lightweight framework and most likely does not provide such functionality. You could use `File(...)` to get an uploaded file binary through the form and it is up to you how to process contents after that.